# vscode ignoring jsconfig.json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code, vscode-jsconfig

I have just added the jsconfig.json file to my node and react project. It is at the top level of the project.

here is what is in it:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src"
  }
}
```

It is having no effect. I have reload the vscode window. I have restarted my app.

I even tried to add errors to the file like so :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src"
  }
}s;ldfkjs;al
```

It has no effect. So VScode is simply ignoring the file.

EDITED:
The project is a node module that is imported by my React APP

Comment: Can you explain "ignoring"? What are you expecting VSCode to do with the file?

Comment: If I specify absolute paths, it will error. But that is what `baseUrl` is for.